# Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:monitor' that satisfies the version constraints

Tags: testing, fragment, android-fragmentscenario

**I am getting this error while running a fragment test which is a simple test that launches fragmentInContatiner:**

```
    Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:monitor' that satisfies the version constraints: 
   Dependency path 'Host Work.features:ui-home:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0'
   Constraint path 'Host Work.features:ui-home:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:{strictly 1.1.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.1
   Dependency path 'Host Work.features:ui-home:unspecified' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.0-alpha02' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.1'
```

**Here are my gradle dependencies that are creating this problem:**

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-alpha02'
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 14):

I found the problem and had to exclude the core module from fragment-testing dependency. It was this conflict that was creating the problem.

```
debugImplementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.5") {
    exclude group: "androidx.test", module : "core"
}
```

Comment: How did you figure out that it was the fragment-testing dependency? Any recommendations for someone that's new to gradle for figuring this out?

Comment: @VIN From documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/test and from sample codes

Comment: @VIN, you can see the dependency tree with `./gradlew :app:dependencies` (there might be a way in AndroidStudio too). From that, you can see what versions have been picked and why.

Answer (score 2):

Just excluding `module: core` didn't worked for me. I had same problem and I changed my espresso dependencies in this way successfully:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
debugImplementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.6") {
    exclude group:'androidx.test', module:'monitor'
}
```

As stated in this official issue: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/481